# Chapter 2, Section 5 of Chavel's book “Eigenvalue In Riemann Geometry" is about the zero-point distribution of the derivatives of eigenfunctions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, eigenvalues, sturm-liouville-theory

In Chapter 2, Section 5 of Chavel's book, regarding the Neumann eigenvalues of the Laplacian in space forms, how did Chavel determine that $T'_{l,j}$ has ($j-1$) zeros? I have consulted books on the Sturm–Liouville theory and could only confirm that $T_{l,j}$ has ($j-1$) zeros. How can one obtain the distribution of zeros of the derivative of the eigenfunctions?

Comment: It is best if questions are as self contained as possible, so, for example, including the definition of $T'_{l, j}$. \\ TeX note: please use $T'$ or $T^\prime$ `T'` or `T^\prime`, not $T^{'}$ `T^{'}`.  Notice that the prime in the latter is too high and too small.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: This is almost definitional: $\lambda_{l,j}$ is chosen so that $T'_{l,j}$ has its $j^{th}$ zero at $\delta$.

Comment: Compare Chavel's general description of the process to the calculation of Neumann eigenvalues in an open ball of radius $\delta$.

Comment: @尼尔 Thank you for your response, but I still want to know if we don't consider it as a Bessel equation, can we still determine the number of zeros of the derivative using the general Sturm-Liouville theory?

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for your response !